# Joining two dataframes then combining data in fields with same name using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have seven dataframes with hundreds of rows each(don't ask) that I need to combine on a column. I know how to use the inner join functionality. In Pandas. What I need help with is that there are instances where these seven data frames have columns with the same names. In those instances, I would like to combine the data therein and delimit with a semicolon.

For example, if Row 1 in DF1 through DF7 have the same identifier, I would like Col1 in each dataframe (given they have the same name) to be combined to read:

dfdata1; dfdata2; ...;dfdata7

In cases where a column name is unique, I'd like it to appear in the final combined dataframe.

I've included a simple example

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame([['Banana', 'Sally', 'CA'], ['Apple', 'Gretta', 'MN'], ['Orange', 'Samantha', 'NV']],
                     columns=['Product', 'Cashier', 'State'])
  

data2 = pd.DataFrame([['Shirt','', 'CA'], ['Shoe', 'Trish', 'MN'], ['Socks', 'Paula', 'NM', 'Hourly']],
```

This yields two dataframes:

[image]

If we were to use an outer merge on state:

```
pd.merge(data1,data2,on='State',how='outer')
```

[image]

What I want is something more like this:

[image]

Is this doable in pandas or will I have to merge the first two, combine the columns with the same names, then move on to combine THAT with the third one etc. I'm trying to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of merging, concatenate

```
# concatenate and groupby to join the strings
df = pd.concat([data1, data2]).groupby('State', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: '; '.join(el for el in x if pd.notna(el)))
print(df)
  State        Product        Cashier    Type
0    CA  Banana; Shirt        Sally;         
1    MN    Apple; Shoe  Gretta; Trish        
2    NM          Socks          Paula  Hourly
3    NV         Orange       Samantha
```